# CRMWebAPI - How to work with Entity reference?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I use [CRMWebAPI](https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI) for CRUD operations with CRM. How can I work there with a entity reference?

For example when I want to update parent account attribute on the Account entity, where the parent account attribute is Lookup to another account.

Something like this:

```
dynamic updateObject = new ExpandoObject();
updateObject.parentaccountid = the_entity_reference;
dynamic updateResult = await api.Update("accounts", new Guid("1111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555"), updateObject, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Referred this code sample](https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/blob/master/dotnet/Xrm.Tools.WebAPI.Test/ActionTests.cs) and able to compose this. Please test it.

```
dynamic updateObject = new ExpandoObject();

Guid accountID = new Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx");    
var parAcctIndexer = updateObject as IDictionary<string, Object>;
parAcctIndexer["parentaccountid@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(" + accountID.ToString() + ")";

dynamic updateResult = await api.Update("accounts", new Guid("1111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555"), updateObject, false);
```